# {W104} Unqualified property elements are not allowed. Treated as a relative URI. ERROR

Tags: xml, xslt, rdf, owl

I got a sample xml like this:

```
<a>
<apple color="red"/>
<banana color="yellow"/>
<sugar taste="sweet"/>
<cat size="small"/>
</a>
```

I convert it to OWL using XSLT below:

Then i test the result using this site (http://www.mindswap.org/2003/pellet/demo), and it generate error "{W104} Unqualified property elements are not allowed. Treated as a relative URI. ERROR" to me, what's wrong with the OWL btw ? From what am i doing is just select the given text into class, datatype and object.

This is the output:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is lines like:

```
<element xmlns="">apple</element>
```

which is setting an empty default namespace. That's a consequence of your xslt, where the default namespace you want isn't scoped correctly. Try adding it to the `xsl:stylesheet` element.

Comment: dude, u saved my life ~ i have been wondering around this error for 4-5 days ~ and just adding it to the "xsl:stylesheet" it works completely ~ thanks

Answer (score 1):

It'll be lines like this, I would think:

```
<element xmlns="">banana</element>
<attribute xmlns="">small</attribute>
```

You need to provide a namespace, so that `element` is not an unqualified XML element, or have the xslt not generate an empty `xmlns` attribute so that the element will be treated as relative to the `xml:base`. Personally, I'd fix the correct namespace in the generated output.

**Addendum**
But also think about the modelling here. What does an ObjectProperty having an attribute of `small` or `yellow` actually mean? The *property itself*, being an abstract notion, is neither small nor yellow.

Comment: I also not sure why is it "small" and "yellow" are in the ObjectProperty, i was asked to do so by my guider.